# PyQt: Manipulating svg files for QGraphicsSvgItem

Tags: python, qt, svg, pyqt

My main objective is to change stroke width of a given svg file, but I see no inbuilt method to do so.

The width's are unfortunately hardcoded in the svg file, and my initial thought was to buffer the data, and edit it in memory before changing the rendered svg file. But that is just additional processing overhead.

Next, I looked into converting the svg to a dom - tree like structure, but then I might have to save it back again before loading it in the QGraphicsSvgItem, which would be a bizarre intermediate step for changing line thickness on the fly.

Here is an example svg file,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="3.2421772mm"
   height="6.1269817mm"
   viewBox="0 0 3.2421772 6.1269817"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg12403"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)"
   sodipodi:docname="Bag.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs12397" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="-229.58734"
     inkscape:cy="-219.85002"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="705"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata12400">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-43.736054,-84.5377)">
    <g
       id="use26359"
       transform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,-3.9887501,73.928193)">
      <desc
         id="desc12960">Bag</desc>
      <title
         id="title12962">Bag</title>
      <path
         d="m 180.61365,49.4094 v 13.609494 h 11.78107 V 49.4094 C 192.27,46.875236 189.67,44.872517 186.50494,44.872517 c -3.16454,0 -5.76448,2.002719 -5.89129,4.536883 z m 2.94488,-9.07316 2.94641,4.536277 2.9449,-4.536277 z"
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.66862381"
         id="path12964"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
      <g
         style="stroke-width:1.31504369"
         id="g12968"
         transform="matrix(0.507302,0,0,0.50958516,89.699529,-958.6518)">
        <path
           d="m 179.211,1978.199 v 26.707 h 23.223 v -26.707 c -0.246,-4.972 -5.371,-8.902 -11.61,-8.902 -6.238,0 -11.363,3.93 -11.613,8.902 z m 5.805,-17.804 5.808,8.902 5.805,-8.902 z m 5.808,0 v 8.902"
           style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.93203717;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
           id="path12966"
           inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

As you can see, there is a stroke width value in the style attribute for the path.

Is there a simple less obnoxious "hack" way of achieving this?

Comment: The [QGraphicsSvgItem documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicssvgitem.html) says that you don't have to give it a file name but can use a [QSvgRenderer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgrenderer.html) instead. You can load the file, edit it in memory and pass this to the `QSvgRenderer` constructor. Finally set the `QSvgRenderer` in the `QGraphicsSvgItem`. This way there is no need to save the edited SVG back to file and the processing overhead is minimal.

Comment: That wad my thought exactly, but the part of editing it in memory is the issue, xml-dom will convert it to a minidom object that i will have to save again to maintain svg format, loading it as a file will mean i will have to look up the style attribute letter by letter to change it

Comment: Still not sure what the problem is with just using the [replace](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method of the build in string class. Unless with _'letter by letter'_ you mean that you don't know the exact number of the stroke-width in the file. In that case you could use a regular expression's [sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) method to replace a string pattern.

Comment: Yes i used the sub method in re, but I was interested in a method of doing this in qt, because everytime i want to change the stroke width (lets say using a slider) the file is loaded, then manipulated and passed to the renderer. Then there is the issue of objects already drawn on the scene as well